# Search box is taller in Firefox despite CSS being the same

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox

I just found a issue in Firefox where an input element with the type `search` is displayed differently with same css style. Here's the code.

```
<input style="height:29px;" type="search">
<input style="height:29px;" type="submit" value="search">
```

on Webkit browsers like Chrome, Safari and Opera there is not an issue, but on Firefox of the latest version it acts differently. The search box is taller. How to fix this with CSS or JavaScript?

Comment: If you are using css you may want to try a css reset such as normalize.css

Normalize.css makes browsers render all elements more consistently and in line with modern standards. It precisely targets only the styles that need normalizing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try to add following element into CSS ?

**CSS**

```
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    height:29px;
    border: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    margin-top:-2px; 
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="search">
<input type="submit" value="search">
```

jsfiddle : `http://jsfiddle.net/w2mmX/1/`

it should solve this issue.